# How to drop a list item of a column to another list item of another column using React beautiful dnd?

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I am working on the [Multidrag Pattern](https://react-beautiful-dnd.netlify.com/?selectedKind=Multi%20drag&selectedStory=pattern&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel), but I want that, in the second column there will be some items and I will drag an item from the first column and drop it on one of the list items on the second column instead of that column. Please help me.

Example: This is the [initial dnd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RV7wE.png)
I want like : [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNHQt.png)

Comment: check this code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/ql08j35j3q , is this you need or show us what you've tried so far ?

Comment: No, I have done this so far as shown in the sandbox. I need to drag a list item of left column  (say item - 0) exactly on a list item of right column (say item-10). 
After dropping the list item of right column will display [item-10 item 0].

Comment: I have also added 2 images, please check it out.

Comment: if i drag vb from left side to right side , it should placed as same as ju in the right column , is that you need ?

Comment: It is quite difficult to understand what you are trying to do, You mean you want to replace that item on drag?

Comment: @Jayavel, yes, that's what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am understanding your question entirely. It sounds like you would like to combine two items. If so, I have good news. We will soon be shipping a new combining api in `react-beautiful-dnd` which will allow you to combine `Draggable`s

You track progress on the feature here: https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/511

Comment: Yes, you got me. I want two columns with some items. Items of first column should be `Draggable` and dropped on items on the second column. As soon as it is dropped on one of the items on the second column they will be combined.